# How to add pipe to input field in Angular

Tags: html, angular

I need to add `currency` pipe to my `total` column, but the problem is that it is an `input` field, How do I do that?

```
<div id="forms" class="page-layout simple fullwidth" fxLayout="column">
    <button routerLink='/searchLoan' mat-raised-button fxFlex="4" class="btn-style-1" style="align-self: flex-end;margin-right: 30px;margin-top: 15px;">View
        List</button>
    <div class="content p-24">
        <div class="mb-24" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start" fxLayout.gt-md="row">

            <mat-card>
                <mat-card-title style='margin-top: -15px;'>New Loan</mat-card-title>

                <mat-card-content>
                    <form class="p-24 mr-24" fxLayout="column" fxLayoutAlign="start" fxFlex="1 0 auto" name="form" [formGroup]="newLoanForm">
                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100%" class="pr-4">
                                <mat-label>Customer </mat-label>
                                <mat-select required formControlName='customerId'>
                                    <mat-option *ngFor='let customer of customerList' [value]="customer.customerId">
                                        {{customer.name}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                                <mat-icon matSuffix>face</mat-icon>
                            </mat-form-field>

                            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                                <button type="button" mat-stroked-button class='addCustomerButton' (click)="openCustomerDialog()" fxFlex='100'>Add
                                    <mat-icon matSuffix>add_box</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex>

                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="row" fxFlex="50%" class="pr-4">
                                <mat-label>Referring Organization</mat-label>
                                <mat-select required formControlName="orginizationId">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor='let organization of organizationList' [value]="organization.orginizationId">
                                        {{organization.orginizationName}}
                                    </mat-option>
                                </mat-select>
                                <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">work_outline</mat-icon>
                                <mat-error> Referring Organization is required!</mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>

                            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                                <button type="button" mat-stroked-button class='addCustomerButton' (click)="openOrganizationDialog()" fxFlex='100'>Add
                                    <mat-icon matSuffix>add_box</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                            </div>

                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="row" fxFlex="50%" class="pr-4">
                                <mat-label>Sales Person</mat-label>
                                <mat-select required formControlName="salesPersonId">
                                    <mat-option *ngFor="let person of salesPersonList" [value]="person.salesPersonId">
                                        {{person.name}}
                                    </mat-option>

                                </mat-select>
                                <mat-icon matSuffix class="secondary-text">supervised_user_circle</mat-icon>
                                <mat-error> Sales Person is required!</mat-error>
                            </mat-form-field>
                            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                                <button type="button" mat-stroked-button class='addCustomerButton' (click)="openSalesPersonDialog()" fxFlex='100'>Add
                                    <mat-icon matSuffix>add_box</mat-icon>
                                </button>
                            </div>
                        </div>

                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="row" fxFlex="50%" class="pr-4">
                                <mat-label>Invoice Number</mat-label>
                                <input type='number' formControlName="invoiceNumber" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Invoice Number" required>
                                <mat-icon matSuffix>receipt</mat-icon>
                            </mat-form-field>

                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="row" fxFlex="50%" class="pr-4">
                                <mat-label>Invoice Date</mat-label>
                                <!-- <input type='date' matInput name="" id="" formControlName="invoiceDate" placeholder="Invoice Date" required> -->
                                <input matInput [(ngModel)]="loanDate" ngModel [ngModelOptions]="{standalone: true}" [matDatepicker]="picker" placeholder="Choose a date" required>
                                <mat-datepicker-toggle matSuffix [for]="picker"></mat-datepicker-toggle>
                                <mat-datepicker #picker></mat-datepicker>


                                <!-- <mat-icon matSuffix>date_range</mat-icon> -->
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>

                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                            <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                                <mat-label>Notes</mat-label>
                                <textarea matInput name="" id="" formControlName="notes" placeholder="Notes" required></textarea>
                                <mat-icon matSuffix>assignment</mat-icon>
                            </mat-form-field>
                        </div>
                        <form [formGroup]="loanProductForm">
                            <table style="overflow-x: auto;display: inline-block; white-space: nowrap;">
                                <thead>
                                    <tr class='tableHeader'>
                                        <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                                            <td fxFlex="14" class="pr-4">Name</td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14" class="pr-4">Price</td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14" class="pr-4">Loan Term</td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14" class="pr-4">Quantity</td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14" class="pr-4">Deposit</td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14" class="pr-4">Total</td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14" class="pr-4">Action</td>
                                        </div>
                                    </tr>
                                </thead>
                                <tbody>
                                    <tr formArrayName="products" *ngFor="let product of loanProductForm.get('products').controls; let i = index">
                                        <div [formGroupName]="i" fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                                            <td fxFlex="14">
                                                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                                                    <mat-label>Product </mat-label>
                                                    <mat-select formControlName="productId" (selectionChange)="onChangedProduct($event, i)" [id]="'productId' + i" required>
                                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let product of productList" [value]="product.productId">
                                                            {{product.name}}
                                                        </mat-option>
                                                    </mat-select>

                                                </mat-form-field>
                                            </td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14">
                                                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                                                    <mat-label>Price </mat-label>
                                                    <input type='number' (keyup)="onPriceChange($event)" matInput formControlName="price" [id]="'price' + i" name="" placeholder="Price" required>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                            </td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14">
                                                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                                                    <mat-label>Loan Term </mat-label>
                                                    <mat-select formControlName="loanTermId" [id]="'loanTermId' + i" required>
                                                        <mat-option *ngFor="let loanTerm of loanTermList" [value]="loanTerm.loanTermId">
                                                            {{loanTerm.numberOfMonths}}
                                                        </mat-option>
                                                    </mat-select>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                            </td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14">
                                                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                                                    <mat-label>Quantity </mat-label>
                                                    <input type='number' formControlName="quantity" [id]="'quantity' + i" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Quantity" required>

                                                </mat-form-field>
                                            </td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14">
                                                <mat-form-field appearance="outline" fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                                                    <mat-label>Deposit </mat-label>
                                                    <input type='number' formControlName="deposit" [id]="'deposit' + i" matInput name="" id="" placeholder="Deposit" required>
                                                </mat-form-field>
                                            </td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14">
                                                <div fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                                                    <!-- <mat-label>Total:&nbsp;&nbsp;</mat-label> -->
                                                    <input [disabled]="true" formControlName="total" [id]="'total' + i" matInput name="total" class='total' id="" placeholder="Total" style="color:black; font-weight:bold; width: unset;" required>
                                                </div>
                                            </td>
                                            <td fxFlex="14">
                                                <div fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
                                                    <!-- <button class='deleteButton' mat-stroked-button style="color:red" > -->
                                                    <span class='deleteButton' (click)='deleteProduct(i)'><mat-icon >delete</mat-icon></span>
                                                    <!-- </button> -->
                                                </div>
                                            </td>

                                        </div>
                                    </tr>
                                    <tr>
                                        <td fxFlex="10">
                                            <div fxLayout="row" fxLayoutAlign="start center" fxFlex="1 0 auto">
                                                <button type="button" mat-stroked-button class='addBtn btn-style-2' fxFlex='100' (click)='addProductButtonClick()'>Add
                                                    <mat-icon>add_box</mat-icon>
                                                </button>
                                            </div>
                                        </td>
                                    </tr>
                                </tbody>
                            </table>
                        </form>
                        <button mat-raised-button fxFlex="15" [disabled]="dataSending" id='submitButton' class="btn-style-1" style="align-self: flex-end;margin-right: 30px;margin-top: 15px;" (click)="addNewLoan()">
                            <img *ngIf="dataSending" style="width : 24px"
                                src="../../../../../assets//images/spinner.gif" />&nbsp;Save</button>
                    </form>
                </mat-card-content>


            </mat-card>
        </div>
    </div>
</div>
```

and here is my `component` file code

```
import { Component, OnInit } from '@angular/core';
import { Router } from '@angular/router';
import { NewCustomerComponent } from '../../../../layout/components/customer/new-customer/new-customer.component';
import { NewOrganizationComponent } from '../../../../layout/components/organization/new-organization/new-organization.component';
import { AddSalesPersonComponent } from '../../../../layout/components/Sales/add-sales-person/add-sales-person.component'
import { FormGroup, FormControl, FormArray, FormBuilder, Validators } from '@angular/forms';
import { CustomerService } from '../../../../services/customer/customer.service';
import { SalesPersonService } from 'app/services/sales person/sales-person.service';
import { OrganizationService } from 'app/services/organization/organization.service';
import { ProductService } from '../../../../services/product/product.service';
import { LoanTermService } from '../../../../services/loanTerms/loan-term.service'
import { LoanService } from '../../../../services/loan/loan.service';
import { LoanProductService } from '../../../../services/loanProducts/loan-product.service';
import * as _moment from 'moment'
import { Observable, pipe } from 'rxjs';
import { map, debounceTime, distinctUntilChanged } from 'rxjs/operators';
import { MatDialog, MatDialogRef, MAT_DIALOG_DATA } from '@angular/material/dialog';
import PNotify from 'pnotify/dist/es/PNotify';
@Component({
  selector: 'app-new-loan',
  templateUrl: './new-loan.component.html',
  styleUrls: ['./new-loan.component.scss']
})
export class NewLoanComponent implements OnInit {

  constructor(
    private _formBuilder: FormBuilder,
    private customerService: CustomerService,
    private salesPersonService: SalesPersonService,
    private organizationService: OrganizationService,
    private productService: ProductService,
    private loanTermService: LoanTermService,
    private loanService: LoanService,
    private loanProductService: LoanProductService,
    private router: Router,
    public dialog: MatDialog
  ) { }
  loanDate;
  dataSending = false;
  installmentStartDate;
  newLoanForm: FormGroup;
  loanProductForm: FormGroup
  customerList;
  salesPersonList;
  organizationList;
  productList;
  loanTermList;
  totalValue = 0;
  // price;
  // quantity;
  // deposit;
  newRow = { productId: '', price: '', loanTermId: '', quantity: '', deposit: '', total: '' };

  ngOnInit() {
    this.newLoanForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      customerId: ['', Validators.required],
      orginizationId: ['', Validators.required],
      salesPersonId: ['', Validators.required],
      invoiceNumber: ['', Validators.required],
      invoiceDate: ['', Validators.required],
      notes: ['', Validators.required]
    });

    this.loanProductForm = this._formBuilder.group({
      products: this._formBuilder.array([
        this.addProductFormGroup()
      ])
    });
    this.loanProductForm.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(20)).subscribe((values) => {

      (this.loanProductForm.get('products') as FormArray).controls.forEach(group => {
        let total = (group.get('quantity').value * group.get('price').value) - group.get('deposit').value;
        group.get('total').setValue(total);
      });

    });

    this.getCustomers();
    this.getSalesPersons();
    this.getOrganizations();
    this.getProducts();
    this.getLoanTerms();


  }
  async getCustomers() {
    this.customerList = await this.customerService.getCustomers().toPromise();
    this.customerList.sort((a, b) => (a.customerId < b.customerId) ? 1 : -1);
  }
  async getSalesPersons() {
    this.salesPersonList = await this.salesPersonService.getSalesPersons().toPromise();
    this.salesPersonList.sort((a, b) => (a.salesPersonId < b.salesPersonId) ? 1 : -1);
  }
  async getOrganizations() {
    this.organizationList = await this.organizationService.getOrganizations().toPromise();
    this.organizationList.sort((a, b) => (a.orginizationId < b.orginizationId) ? 1 : -1);
  }
  getProducts() {
    this.productService.getProducts().subscribe((response) => {
      this.productList = response;
      this.productList.sort((a, b) => (a.productId < b.productId) ? 1 : -1);

    });

  }
  getLoanTerms() {
    this.loanTermService.getLoanTerms().subscribe((response) => {
      this.loanTermList = response;
    });
  }
  addTableRow() {
    this.newRow = { productId: '', price: '', loanTermId: '', quantity: '', deposit: '', total: '' };
    // this.tableRows.push(this.newRow)
  }
  // isSame(prev, next) {
  //   return (prev.value === next.value)
  //     && (prev.quantity === next.quantity);
  // }

  addProductFormGroup(): FormGroup {
    return this._formBuilder.group({
      productId: ['', Validators.required],
      price: [0, Validators.required],
      loanTermId: ['', Validators.required],
      quantity: [0, Validators.required],
      deposit: [0, Validators.required],
      total: [0, Validators.required],
    });
  }

  addProductButtonClick(): void {
    // let newGroup = this.addProductFormGroup();
    // newGroup.markAsUntouched();

    // (<FormArray>this.loanProductForm.get('products')).push(newGroup);
    // const indexOfLastProduct = this.loanProductForm['controls']['products'].length - 1;
    // this.loanProductForm['controls']['products']['controls'][indexOfLastProduct].markAsUntouched();

    // console.log('Loan Products: ', this.loanProductForm.value)

    (<FormArray>this.loanProductForm.get('products')).push(this.addProductFormGroup());
    console.log('Loan Products: ', this.loanProductForm.value);

  }

  onPriceChange(e) {
    //Nothing here, just for reference
  }
  onChangedProduct(event, index) {
    const product =
      this.productList.find(product => product.productId === event.value);
    if (product) {
      // console.log('Product is: ', product)
      this.loanProductForm.get(['products', index + '', 'price']).patchValue(product.recomendedRetailPrice);
      const loanTermId = null; // you need to find the loanTermId from loanTermList
      this.loanProductForm.get(['products', index + '', 'loanTermId']).patchValue(product.loanTermId);
    }
  }


  async addNewLoan() {

    this.newLoanForm.value.invoiceDate = this.loanDate.format();
    let loanProducts = this.loanProductForm.value.products;
    this.newLoanForm.value.loanProducts = loanProducts;
    let loanTerm;
    // document.getElementById('submitButton').style.display = 'none';
    this.dataSending = true;

    // Calculating installment start Date
    if (this.loanDate.date() <= 14) {
      this.installmentStartDate = this.loanDate.add(1, 'M');
      this.installmentStartDate = this.loanDate.date(10);
    }
    else {
      this.installmentStartDate = this.loanDate.add(2, 'M');
      this.installmentStartDate = this.loanDate.date(10);
    }
    // Adding installment start date to each product
    loanProducts.forEach(product => {
      product.installmentStartDate = this.installmentStartDate.format();
    });


    console.log('LoanProducts: ', loanProducts);

    let productsProcessed = 0;
    loanProducts.forEach(async product => {

      await this.loanTermService.getLoanTerm(product.loanTermId).subscribe((response: any) => {
        // console.log('Number of months: ', response.numberOfMonths)
        loanTerm = response.numberOfMonths;
        product.monthlyInstallment = product.total / loanTerm;
      }, error => {
        console.log('Error while retrieving loanTermId: ', error);
      });
      productsProcessed++;
      if (productsProcessed === loanProducts.length) {

        // Posting loan after the response of loanTerms Service
        this.loanService.postLoan(this.newLoanForm.value).subscribe((response: any) => {

          console.log('Loan added successfully: ', response);
          PNotify.success({
            title: 'Loan added Successfully',
            text: 'Redirecting to list page',
            minHeight: '75px'
          });
          // document.getElementById('submitButton').style.display = 'initial';
          this.dataSending = false;
          this.router.navigate(['searchLoan']);

        }, (error) => {
          console.log('Error occured while adding loan: ', error);
          PNotify.error({
            title: 'Error occured while adding loan',
            text: 'Failed to add new loan',
            minHeight: '75px'
          });
          // document.getElementById('submitButton').style.display = 'initial';
          this.dataSending = false;
        });
        // Posting of loan ends here
      }
    });




    this.newLoanForm.value.loanProducts = loanProducts;
    console.log('Loan Products: ', this.loanProductForm.value);

  }
  deleteProduct(i) {
    (this.loanProductForm.get('products') as FormArray).removeAt(i);
  }
  // Opening of dialogs
  openCustomerDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewCustomerComponent, {
      width: '700px',
      height: '600px',
      data: {
        view: 'dialog'
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(async result => {
      console.log('OpenCustomer Dialog was closed');
      await this.getCustomers().then(() => {
        let customerPreSelectId = this.customerList[0].customerId;
        this.newLoanForm.patchValue({
          customerId: customerPreSelectId
        })
      });
    });

  }

  openOrganizationDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(NewOrganizationComponent, {
      width: '800px',
      height: '600px',
      data: {
        view: 'dialog'
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(async result => {
      console.log('OpenOrganizations was closed');
      await this.getOrganizations().then(() => {
        let organizationPreSelectId = this.organizationList[0].orginizationId;
        this.newLoanForm.patchValue({
          orginizationId: organizationPreSelectId
        });
      });

    });
  }
  openSalesPersonDialog(): void {
    const dialogRef = this.dialog.open(AddSalesPersonComponent, {
      width: '700px',
      height: '600px',
      data: {
        view: 'dialog'
      }
    });
    dialogRef.afterClosed().subscribe(async result => {
      console.log('OpenSalesPerson dialog was closed');
      await this.getSalesPersons().then(() => {
        let salesPersonPreSelectId = this.salesPersonList[0].salesPersonId;
        this.newLoanForm.patchValue({
          salesPersonId: salesPersonPreSelectId
        })
      });
    });
  }
}
```

I already tried using a regular method, but it was not working.
Picture for better understanding.

[image: Picture for better understanding]

Comment: is this rendered using a *ngFor ?

Comment: No, the new row is added when the user clicks on the `Add` button

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In this line of code...

```
this.loanProductForm.valueChanges.pipe(debounceTime(20)).subscribe((values) => {

  (this.loanProductForm.get('products') as FormArray).controls.forEach(group => {
    let total = (group.get('quantity').value * group.get('price').value) - group.get('deposit').value;
    **group.get('total').setValue(myPipe.transform(total));**
  });

});
```

I have just changed this line in your code `group.get('total').setValue(myPipe.transform(total));` and added currency pipe class and call `transform()` method and then call this in setValue() of `total` form-control.

**Update 1**

How to include pipe in your component.ts...

```
import { CurrencyPipe } from './currency.pipe';

 @Component({
   selector: 'app-root',
   templateUrl: './app.component.html',
   styleUrls: ['./app.component.css'],
   providers: [ CurrencyPipe]
 })

 export class AppComponent {

      constructor(private currencyPipe: CurrencyPipe) {}

         // ...
 }
```

Comment: I tried the `group.get('total').setValue(CurrencyPipe.transform(total));` 
but its giving error, `property transform does not exist of type CurrencyPipe`

Comment: @Lint Check out my `Updated-1` answer and add properly currency pipe to component then you have to inject it in constructor() then you can acces `transform()`

Comment: Now I'm getting this error
`NewLoanComponent_Host.ngfactory.js? [sm]:1 ERROR NullInjectorError: StaticInjectorError(AppModule)[NewLoanComponent -> CurrencyPipe]: 
  StaticInjectorError(Platform: core)[NewLoanComponent -> CurrencyPipe]: 
    NullInjectorError: No provider for CurrencyPipe!`

Comment: have you add Currencypipe to  providers array  of module or not

Comment: No, how do I do that ?

Comment: YES you have to do that

Comment: Alright, it started working, now the problem is that it is showing the value in `$` whereas I need the value in `KES` currency, how to do that ?

Comment: Let us [continue this discussion in chat](https://chat.stackoverflow.com/rooms/205530/discussion-between-gaurangdhorda-and-lint).

Answer (score 3):

You can use **[value]** property to use your pipe

```
<td fxFlex="14">
 <div fxFlex="100" class="pr-4">
    <!-- <mat-label>Total:&nbsp;&nbsp;</mat-label> -->
    <input [disabled]="true" [value]="loanProductForm.get('products').controls[i].value.total | yourPipe"  formControlName="total" [id]="'total' + i" matInput name="total" class='total' id=""
        placeholder="Total" style="color:black; font-weight:bold; width: unset;" required>
</div>
```

where  **yourPipe** is your custom pipe

Comment: Sorry, but its not working. 
Its giving me error `Cannot read property 'value' of null`

Comment: How would Angular know which `total` to get, because its an array

Comment: Can you post your parent formGroup? according to your question i have posted the answer. I can modify the same if the parent form group to which you have pushed the child formGroup is present in the question.

Comment: I posted my complete files, `component` and `template` please have a look now

Comment: Sorry, but it is still not working, pipe is there when I've not selected the product, but as soon as I select a product from dropdown, it removes the pipe and just a normal number is written there

Answer (score 2):

try [value] property, it will work

```
 <input #username [value]="username.value | currency" [disabled]="true" formControlName="total" [id]="'total' + i" matInput name="total" class='total' id=""
        placeholder="Total" style="color:black; font-weight:bold; width: unset;" required>
```

I tried adding **#username [value]="username.value | currency"** and its working

Comment: @Lint try this solution and let me know